# bool with => and || .. what does it means?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know what means:

```cs
public bool Active;
```

But can someone tell me what this line below means:

```cs
public bool Active => isActive || IsRequestActive;
```

specially the `=>` and the `||`

thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties

Comment: And the || means 'or'. The final expression is true if any of the two arguments is true.
So in your example the variable Active is true if isActive or IsRequestActive (or both) is true.

Comment: Thats a [Lambda Expresion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows a way to declare a [read-only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties) which is a feature of `C# 6.0`.

`||` is a [conditional logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-), the Active property value will be true if at least one of the fields isActive/IsRequestActive is true.

Comment: The expression-valued property syntax is new, read-only properties have been around for a while.  Before we had the `=>` short-hand, the identical effect is achieved by `public bool Active { get { return isActive || IsRequestActive; } }`